# driven off the jar file compression

Tags: java, jar, sikuli

How to run a `Sikulix.class` ?

This is the error I'm getting.

```
D:\test_sikuli\sikulix>java -cp D:\test_sikuli\sikulix\org\sikuli\ide SikuliIDE
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SikuliIDE (wrong name: org/sikuli/ide/SikuliIDE)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please put more details

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add essential parts of your code. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Comment: That's all I received the error.

Comment: But it could succeed as below minutes with the help of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class you want to run is apparently `org.sikuli.ide.SikuliIDE`. You need to set the classpath to the top folder and not to the package folder and use the qualified class name.

```
D:\test_sikuli\sikulix>java -cp D:\test_sikuli\sikulix org.sikuli.ide.SikuliIDE
```